# How to list the existing projects on a Trac server using xmlrpc?

Tags: xml-rpc, trac

I think it's all in the subject.

It seems that XMLRPC Plugin can only export info about a precise project but not about the existing projects.

I have been looking for some plugin doing that for hours but nothing comes out. Are you aware of something capable to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "projects", do you mean different Trac instances located on the same server?

If so, then there's no way to do this currently.  Trac instances are effectively independent and there's no central "Trac server" that could give you the information that you need.  Individual Trac instances don't really know anything about any other instances on the server.  Future releases of Trac that include true multi-project support may very well change this, however.

One way you can work around this is to store the names of all of the Trac projects on a wiki page, and then fetch that page via XMLRPC and parse out the data.  Another workaround is to have the webserver (not Trac) serve up a page that lists all of the projects on the system.  They're not the prettiest solutions, but they should at least give you the functionality that you need.